# Are (1R,2S)‐1,2‐dibromocyclopentane and (1R,3S)‐1,3‐dibromocyclopentane positional isomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, erratum

[image: (1R,2S)‐1,2‐dibromocyclopentane and (1R,3S)‐1,3‐dibromocyclopentane]

Are these positional isomers or not? According to me they are, since Br substituent is located at different positions in both the pictures, but the answer key in one of my mock test websites says they're not. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Does the the website you are using specify why these are not isomers?

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Comment: They are definitely position isomers.. .No doubt in that .The answer in the website must be wrong.